# Adding an entity key when no key is inferred from a view

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I have a database view which joins across a number of tables in SQL Server 2005. It looks something like this:

```
SELECT     
   m1.MenuName AS menu_name, m2.MenuName AS sub_menu_name, p.ProductName, od.amount
FROM         
   dbo.tblMenus AS m1 
FULL OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tblMenus AS m2 
FULL OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tblProductsRelMenus AS pm ON m2.Id = pm.SubMenuId ON m1.Id = pm.MenuId 
FULL OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT     
       dbo.tblOrderDetails.ProductId, SUM(dbo.tblOrderDetails.Ammount) AS amount
    FROM          
       dbo.tblOrderDetails 
    FULL OUTER JOIN
       dbo.tblOrders AS o ON dbo.tblOrderDetails.OrderId = o.OrderId
    WHERE (o.OrderDestroyed = 0)
    GROUP BY dbo.tblOrderDetails.ProductId) AS od 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tblProducts AS p ON od.ProductId = p.ProductId ON pm.ProductId = p.ProductId
```

When I try to create an ADO .Net entity data model it complains about not having a primary key in the SSDL secion. I then found this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163156.aspx

but I don't understand the part about a defining query. Surely I just want a column with unique numbers to define the key, or?

```
  <EntityType Name="SoldItemsView">
    <Key>
       <PropertyRef Name="SoldItemsViewId" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="SoldItemsView" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="menu_name" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="sub_menu_name" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="ProductName" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />
    <Property Name="amount" Type="int" />
  </EntityType>
```

But how do I populate this column with unique numbers?

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: And how's your performance querying against that view ?? ...

Comment: My first thought would be help it out and select tblMenus primary key as well.

Comment: Why would selecting the primary key for tblMenus help it out?

Comment: The performance is fine for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only columns from the view. To define an entity key you must select column (or set of columns) from your view which uniquely identifies record from the view.